# Update word table from excel data using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy data from excel into a word template document and save it with a different name each time. Kind of a mail merge, but I want to activate it from excel.

Below is one with some sample data. But I am getting error on the wordapp open part, also gives me a pop up message that this is not a secure macro in word .

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'

Dim wordapp As Object
Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wordapp.Visible = True



filePath = "C:\Users\drana\OneDrive\Documents\Doc2.docx"
wordapp.Documents.Open filePath
wordapp.Activate


    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
    
    For i = 2 To 5
    
    path_dest = "C:\Users\drana\OneDrive\Documents\Doc2" & i & ".docx"
    
    'read the cells in Excel and save to variables
    xName = Cells(i, 1)
    xage = Cells(i, 2)
    xzip = Cells(i, 3)
    
     If ActiveDocument.Tables.Count >= 1 Then
     ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Text = xName
     ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(3, 2).Text = xage
     ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(5, 2).Text = xzip
     
     End If
    
    wordapp.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs path_dest
    
    Next

WordDoc.Close
wordapp.Quit
Set WordDoc = Nothing
Set wordapp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: "getting error" - you need to provide *specific* information to maximize your chances of getting help.

Comment: If this code is in the workbook containing the worksheet, use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. Also, if you want to dig in deeper and have the Word IntelliSense work in Excel, in (Excel) VBE check `Tools->References>Microsoft Excel 1x.0 Object library`. Then you could start with `Dim wordapp As Word.Application: Set wordapp = New Word.Application` when already after typing `Word.` the IntelliSense would show. After typing `wordapp.` in the next line, the IntelliSense would again show and make things easier.

Comment: What error exactly do you get in the code? Where and when do you run the code? Is it run from service or logon script?

Comment: Do you get any errors with other files on your disk (not from OneDrive)?

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes:

> *ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Text*

- `ActiveDocument` is an object of Word App. It is similar as `ActiveWorkbook` in Excel. You have to use it as `wordApp.ActiveDocument` (in Excel VBA), or use Word `document` object (eg. wordDoc ).
- Use `Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text` to upate a cell in Word tables
- It's worth to read: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)

Note: The code isn't tested coz of lacking sample data.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Dim Sht as Worksheet
    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim wordDoc As Object
    Dim xName, xage, xzip, i as Long
    Dim filePath as String, path_dest as String
    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordApp.Visible = True
    filePath = "C:\Users\drana\OneDrive\Documents\Doc2.docx"
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(filePath)
    For i = 2 To 5
        path_dest = "C:\Users\drana\OneDrive\Documents\Doc2" & i & ".docx"
        'read the cells in Excel and save to variables
        xName = Sht.Cells(i, 1)
        xage = Sht.Cells(i, 2)
        xzip = Sht.Cells(i, 3)
        If wordDoc.Tables.Count >= 1 Then
            wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = xName
            wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(3, 2).Range.Text = xage
            wordDoc.Tables(1).Cell(5, 2).Range.Text = xzip
        End If
        wordDoc.SaveAs path_dest
    Next
    WordDoc.Close
    wordApp.Quit
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tallet, Thank you for the suggested changes. I tried it but I still get issue in the line  Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")   Also a pop up sayin word does not support the macro.

Comment: Please mention the *exact* text of the error messages you get.  "issue" is not a useful description of what you're seeing when you run your code.

Comment: @Ranajit As per Tim's comments, you should provide detailed information about the issue to receive assistance from SO users.

Comment: Hi Guys, Sorry didnt mention the exact error. On running the macro there is at first a pop up window labelled "Microsoft Word Security Notice." It has a warning - Microsoft offie has identified a potential security concern. Microsoft has blocked macros from running because the source of the file is untrusted. There is only one option to Disbale macros. or close the pop up message window. I did close.  It appeared several times.   ..contd comment

Comment: Next on closing it opens Word and in Word there is a pop up message as well " Word found unreadable content in Normal.dotm. Do you want to recover the contents of this document ? if you trust the source of this document click Yes.

Comment: Ban in excel the error is Run-time error'=2146959355 (80080005) Server exection failed. On clicking debug takes me to the line Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Comment: I would think there are some issues with your Word software. Please try to test it with `Word VBA`.  `Dim wordapp As Object: Set wordapp = CreateObject("Word.Application"): wordapp.Visible = True`

Comment: Do you get any errors with other files on your disk (not from OneDrive)?